# Is it possible to read 3rd party cookies

Tags: php, cookies

Im familiar with reading cookies using `php`, but i was wandering if there is a way you can read a users browser cookies set by another 3rd party site (ie. not your own.)

Could somthing like this be written to view all of the users set cookies ?

`print_r($_COOKIE);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

You can only read cookies that come from your own domain. The other cookies are not even sent to your server.

If you could read every cookies the user has, you would be able to obtain personal information such as their facebook password, connection to their bank etc.

It would be a serious breach of privacy, and as such, browsers do not send cookies except those from the same domain.

Comment: What if I have access to the client machine? Are cookies encrypted or protected in any way that prevents a virus to read them?

Comment: The website decides whether it encrypts cookies or not.

Answer (score 3):

## No

When you visit a website, your web browser requests information from that domain (`somedomain.com`), and that third-party domain is allowed to set a cookie. Each domain can only read the cookie it created, so there is no way `anotherdomain.com` could access the cookie created by `somedomain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

To read a cookie you must match the domain that the cookie was originally created under. Browsers consider this a security principle and will not let a site access any cookies that they did not create.

Note that there are several other security considerations that could potentially circumvent this rule, such as [DNSMasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq) in combination with spoofed browser certificates. This is why DNSSec (and SOPA) were such a hot issue; the security hole DNSSec plugs will also protect your cookies from getting stolen from your cookie jar.

There are real-world examples of security holes that have leaked in the past. See [here](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10789_3-9918582-57.html) for an example of an even different security vulnerability from 2008.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, because browser only sends the cookie that set by your domain, usually, it's attached to header of the HTTP request if previously being set by the domain.

Third party cookie are those cookie that set by another domain in the context of the target domain, for example: while opening example.com it might has a banner from another website (example2.com), at this case, if example2.com set cookie it can't be read by example.com because they are from different Origin that Browser prevent even scripts to access it.

Comment: Will example2.com know at this point that I am on example.com ? 
If example.com has included a banner of example2.com, then example2.com might know where it's getting used. Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not.  Otherwise your website would know my bank's login cookie, and you'd be able to steal all my money.  Cookies are only available to the domain that set them.

Comment: @Sven: Not true.  A domain (eg. `domain.com`) can only set cookies for itself.  It can also include **content** from a third-party domain, for instance a banner advert from `ads.com`.  That third-party content can also set cookies, only for *its* domain `ads.com`.  So you might end up with cookies from both `domain.com` and `ads.com`, but each cookie was set by an HTTP response from its own domain.  `domain.com` cannot set cookies for `ads.com`, nor vice versa.

Comment: You are right on this. I'd actually be able to send such a cookie, but the browser would not accept it.